# Conditional wait of pthread never returns in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am trying to implement a queue based worker using pthread. But I have some confusions about `pthread_cond_wait()`.

## class Worker

```
class Worker {
    private:
        pthread_t thread;
        vector<int> queue;
        bool stop;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        pthread_cond_t cond;
    public:
        Worker() {
            stop = false;
            if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
                printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
            }

            if(pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL) != 0){
                printf("\n cond init failed\n");
            }
        }
        ~Worker() {
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
        }
        void interrupt(){
            printf("Going to inturrupt\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond); //broadcast also doesn't work
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            printf("inturrupted \n");
        }
        void condition_lock(){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while(queue.size() == 0){
                printf("Entering conditional lock\n");
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        void *run(){
            printf("run\n");
            while(!stop){
                printf("Going for condition lock");
                printf("size: %d\n",queue.size());
                condition_lock();
                printf("Exit from condition lock");
                while(queue.size() > 0){
                    printf("item: %d\n",queue[0]);
                    queue.pop_back();
                }
            }
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        void push(int value){
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           queue.push_back(value);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        void join(){
            void *status;
            pthread_join(thread,&status);
        }
        static void *run_helper(void* context){
            return ((Worker *)context)->run();
        }
        void stop_thread(){
            stop = true;
            interrupt();
        }
        void start_thread(Worker worker){
            stop = false;
            int status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,run_helper,&worker);
        }
};
```

## Main

```
int main(){
    Worker worker;
    worker.start_thread(worker);
    usleep(500000);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        worker.push(i);
        worker.interrupt();
        usleep(500000);
    }
    worker.stop_thread();
    worker.join();
    printf("Thread exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## output

```
run
Going for condition locksize: 0
Entering conditional lock
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted 
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted 
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted 
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted 
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted 
Going to inturrupt
inturrupted
```

It's never return from `pthread_cond_wait()`. I also don't understand how `pthread_mutex_lock()` is working in `void interrupt()` method because it should be already locked by `void condition_lock()`.

## edit

I have changed two changes in code as suggested.

```
1. use queue.size() == 0 instead of conditional variable. 
2. Use mutex lock/unlock during queue.push_back()
```

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value.  Your `condition_lock(bool condition)` uses the function's local copy of the passed-in boolean value.  The way you've coded it, it takes a snapshot of `(queue.size() == 0)` when called, then waits for its copy of that snapshot to change.  That's never going to happen.

Comment: @AndrewHenle In `condition_lock(bool condition)` it's checking a if statement. First time it's true and execute pthread_cond_wait(). But pthread_cond_wait() doesn't depends on bool condition. So doesn't matter bool condition is pass by value or reference. Isn't it?

Comment: *So doesn't matter bool condition is pass by value or reference. Isn't it?*  It matters.  If you pass-by-value, it's a different boolean variable.  The value of the boolean in your code is one computed at call time from the size of the queue, you get a copy of the state of that computation when the call is made - that computation will not be redone every time you check the value in your function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am calling this in`while` loop. `condition_lock((queue.size() == 0));`. And `condition_lock` doesn't have any `while loop` instead only a `if statement`. So `bool condition` will  be checked only once per call. Sorry I didn't the point.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::thread` and `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`? This code is not at all correct, you need to lock the mutex in `run()` before accessing the queue, and you have a data race on `stop`

Answer (score 2):

Bug here:

```
    void start_thread(Worker worker){ // worker passed by value
                                      // thus it is a copy.
        stop = false;
        int status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,
                         run_helper,&worker); // Address of worker passed to thread.
    }   // worker destroyed here.
```

You are passing the worker in by value (thus getting a copy). The thread is running against this copy. But the copy was destroyed on exit of this function (thus mutex and cond are not valid).

Since `this` and `worker` should be the same thing.

Fix with:

```
     void start_thread(){
          stop = false;
          int status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run_helper, this);
      }
```

This is wrong:

```
   void condition_lock(bool condition){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(condition){
    //  ^^^^ Should be while(<validate some invariant>)
            printf("Entering conditional lock\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
```

You really want to pass a function through here. So that the condition variable can validate the `condition` each time it is revived.

You are mutating the state of the obect without aquiring the lock.

```
    void push(int value){
       queue.push_back(value);
    }
```

There are two threads running through this class. Whenever the state is being modified you need to acquire a lock. This is done in several methods (even modiying `stop` should be done under a lock).

Technically this is not the valid target of C function callback.

```
    static void *run_helper(void* context){
        return ((Worker *)context)->run();
    }
```

C does not know C++ ABI. pthreads is a C library so the only valid pointer you can pass as a callback is a C function.

> I also don't understand how pthread_mutex_lock() is working in void interrupt()

```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);  The call to wait releases the lock
                                     on the mutex. When the thread is woken
                                     up it must reaquire the lock before
                                     the thread exits the call pthread_cond_wait()
                                     This allows another thread to lock the
                                     mutex modify state then call the signal
                                     mrthod before releasing the lock.
                                     this allows interupt() to run as expected.
```

Note: Just because you call signal does not mean the other thread is immediately scheduled  for execution (it just becomes available). Your code is in such a tight loop that it may be an issue aquiring the lock it requires to exit the `pthread_cond_wait()` function.

### Fixed Code:

Though I left the boring fixes that still need to be done for you. You **MUST** check the result of all library calls to validate that they worked. If they don't work then the very least you can do is throw an exception.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// LA: Callback must by C function.
extern "C" void *run_helper(void* context);
class Worker {
    private:
        pthread_t thread;
        vector<int> queue;
        bool stop;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        pthread_cond_t cond;
    public:
        Worker() {
            stop = false;
            if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
                printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
            }

            if(pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL) != 0){
                printf("\n cond init failed\n");
            }
        }
        ~Worker() {
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
        }
        void interrupt(){
            printf("Going to inturrupt\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond); //broadcast also doesn't work
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            printf("inturrupted \n");
        }

        void *run(){
            printf("run\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while(!stop){
                printf("Going for condition lock\n");
                printf("size: %lu\n",queue.size());



                // LA: Moved condition_lock() inline.
                //     This was because we needed the lock around
                //     accessing the state after the wait
                // LA: Check queue size and if we are stopped after being woken
                while(queue.size() == 0 && !stop){
                    printf("Entering conditional lock\n");
                    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
                }
                printf("Exit from condition lock\n");
                while(queue.size() > 0){
                    printf("item: %d\n",queue[0]);
                    queue.pop_back();
                }
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        void push(int value){
            // LA: All state mutation needs to be guarded.
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           queue.push_back(value);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        void join(){
            void *status;
            pthread_join(thread,&status);
        }
        void stop_thread(){
            // LA: All state mutation needs to be guarded.
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            stop = true;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            interrupt();
        }
        void start_thread(){
            int status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,run_helper,this);
        }
};

extern "C" void *run_helper(void* context){
    return ((Worker *)context)->run();
}


int main(){
    Worker worker;
    worker.start_thread();
    usleep(500000);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        worker.push(i);
        worker.interrupt();
        usleep(500000);
    }
    worker.stop_thread();
    worker.join();
    printf("Thread exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it should be a while loop but for now I just want to check once. I have locked mutex before push_back but it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: I am passing the current class object to run_helper() and it's working. `int status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,run_helper,&worker);` Where worker object was created in main function(main thread).

Comment: All the references are indicating the same code for pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal. And I am also confuse about that code, That's why I ask this question. http://www.just4tech.com/2013/09/pthreadcondwait-pthreadcondsignal.html

Comment: @shantanu: The standard does not define an ABI. Thus technically a C function and C++ static member function need not have the same ABI. Since pthreads is a C only library it only understands C functions. Thus you can not pass it a C++ static member function and guarantee it will work. You may find that on some systems they differ and your code will fail.

Comment: I found this error: `std::cout << "Wait: " << pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex) << "\n";` => `Wait: 22`

Comment: Update the `while()` loop you need to also check for `stop`

Comment: Note: C++11 has built in threading classes. There is no need to use a C library to do this work anymore.

Comment: The "fixed code" still has a data race on `stop` and `queue` in `Worker::run()`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Fixed

Comment: Nope, `while (!stop)` is still a race. I would change it to `while (true)` and in the loop body do `if (stop) { pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); pthread_exit(0); }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Just spotted that and fixed.

Comment: Looks good :)  Even better would be to use C++, as you mentioned above: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/945b32b9c14d78d3

Answer (score -1):

> I also don't understand how `pthread_mutex_lock()` is working in `void interrupt()`.

It's not. It's causing a deadlock.

> it should be already locked by `void condition_lock()`.

It is. That's why:

> It's never return from `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: pthread_mutex_lock() is working somehow. I have tested the result. I have added in edited section of question. And I get pthread_cond_wait() example from http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node31.html#SECTION003125000000000000000

Comment: By the way, you misspelt "interrupt".